# How to relation belongs to in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my project I want show name in category and province table and this table i relation with it in user table.

This is my code.

**In controller:**

```
$user=user::with('province','category')->where([['id',$id]])->first();
```

**In model:**

```
//relation with province model (invert relation)
public function province()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\province');
}

//relation with province model (invert relation)
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\category');
}
```

But in return just id is returned not name and other property.

In output show this:

> category_id: 3
>
> province_id: 6

Answer (score 0):

Wrong `$user=user::with('province','category')->where([['id',$id]])->first();`

```
//Use
$user=user::with(['province','category'])->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: try again I am edited it your where([['id',$id]]) is false correct is where('id', $id)

Answer (score 0):

Put the foreign key and local key to relatioships.

```
public function province()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\province','foreign_key','local_key'); // put your FK and LK here
}
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\category','foreign_key','local_key'); // put your FK and LK here
}
```

You can get the result by

```
$user=user::where('id','=',$id)->first();
if(isset($user))
{
  if(isset($user->province))
  {
    //do whatever you want
  }
  if(isset($user->category))
  {
    //do whatever you want
  }
}
```